# Android: Saving or converting captured photo into MultiPageTiff image format

Tags: java, android, tiff

Is it possible in Android to convert or save as  2 or more captured photos into Multipage tiff file?
I'm having a hard time searching saving .tiff file images in android. 
Any sample codes will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. Either find a Java library, or embed a native  library like libTiff. Or, if you like the challenge, you could write your own, that just writes a TIFF "wrapper" around your JPEG files, without decoding/encoding. Should be doable in any case. As it stands, I have to vote for closing your question.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for it? May I ask what's the difference in decoding and encoding TIFF, is encoding creating tiff images? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't checked in my TIFF writing code yet (and it's an `ImageIO` plugin, so it would take some rewriting to make it work on Android). But I'm sure you'll find something using the almighty Google. Also, check out my favorite source for anything TIFF related: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff.html :-)

Comment: We still couldn't find a direct code for converting bitmaps or images to multipage TIFF image format in Android. But as a work around, we used C# web service to convert bitmap to multipage TIFF format instead. Answers are still welcomed. Thanks!